# How do I match a space or the end of a line in a regexp in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I'm tryihng to write a regular expression to match a string in which teh first character is either an "a" or a "b" and then next character is a space or the end of the line.  So I came up with

```
2.4.0 :006 > data = "B U"
 => "B U" 
2.4.0 :007 > data =~ /^[ab](^[[:space:]]|$)/i
 => nil
```

But as you can see, my expression is not matching my string "B U" even though I thought I wrote it properly.  How can I revise it to make it right?

Comment: Space or EOL is just a qualifier. Just tack on a `.*` at the end like `^[aAbB](?:[[:space:]]|$).*` or put it after space `^[aAbB](?:[[:space:]].*|$)`

Comment: f there is something _required_ after space, then this `^[aAbB](?:[[:space:]].+|$)`

Comment: I doubt very much that you'll get a better answer than Wiktor's, but in future please consider waiting longer before making a selection (> 2 hours, perhaps). A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better, possibly just interesting, answers, and short-circuits those still preparing answers. There's no rush, just don't forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm tryihng to write a regular expression to match a string in which teh first character is either an "a" or a "b" and then next character is a space or the end of the line.

The regex in Ruby will look like

```
/^[ab](?:[[:space:]]|$)/i
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/vE1bJac8Ku).

Your `^[ab](^[[:space:]]|$)` pattern matches the line start, then `a` or `b`, then either a whitespace at the start of the string (`^[[:space:]]`, it will never match) or the line end (`$`). So, your regex will match a line that  is equal to `b` or `B`.

Remember to replace `^` with `\A` and `$` with `\z` if you need to match *whole string*, not just a line.

Comment: ...or `/\A[ab](?![^[[:space:]]])/i` or if "whitespace" can be substituted for "space",  `/\A[ab](?!\S)/i`. You needn't keep the spelling mistakes in the first sentence. :-)